# How to replicate data without producing an infinite loop?

Tags: logging, replication

I am writing a remote client that automatically and continuously uploads its logs to a remote server. However while I am designing this process it strikes me that if I log the upload process, I will run into a situation where I continuously produce logging data which has to be uploaded which produces more logging data ad infinitum.

The only work around that I can think of is to exclude uploading logs relating to the upload process.

Can anyone offer any other ideas on this?

Answer (score -1):

If I got you right, it's a question of order. What if an action places the logging record before the action itself takes place?
The upload process logs "uploading logs" and then uploads the logs containing "uploading logs" as it's last record.

If this doesn't help you, it might be due to my lack of knowledge concerning the design of your program. ;-)

Comment: If you lack knowledge, it's generally a good idea to try and acquire it before postulating an answer. As it stands, you answer makes very little sense.